# Windows IoT ICD package export fail

Tags: package, auto-update, provisioning, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to create a provisioning package for Windows 10 IoT to control the auto update settings. I've followed the instructions as shown here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/createiotcorepro

When I try to build the package, I have a failure message. From what I can see, the license used to upgrade the edition is: iotuapcommercial.xml

The instructions say to input the Update Control File for the license. However the file I get from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53899 is an ISO file. I am thinking this is the problem.

How can I get the iotuapcommerical.xml file?

Below is the part of the log with the error:

```
3/2/2017 9:05:19 AM Error PackageProvisioningSettings: Failed to package provisioning settings
3/2/2017 9:05:19 AM Error Exception caught in Export: Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Common.Exceptions.ProvPackageException: PackageProvisioningSettings: Failed to package provisioning settings ---> System.Xml.XmlException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowInvalidChar(Char[] data, Int32 length, Int32 invCharPos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.Datastore.AssetApplySettingProvInfo.GetAssetApplySettingInfoValue()
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.Datastore.AssetApplySettingProvInfo.get_ProvValue()
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.Datastore.ProvXmlWriter.Write(String filePath)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.Datastore.PackageDatastore.WriteProvXmls(SettingEventType eventType, IEnumerable`1 settingProvInfo, IVariant variant)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.Datastore.PackageDatastore.Create(IImageCustomizations imageCustomizations, String directoryPath)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.ProvisioningPackage.PackageProvisioningSettings(IImageCustomizations imageCustomizations)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.ProvisioningPackage.PackageProvisioningSettings(IImageCustomizations imageCustomizations)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.ProvisioningPackage.PackageCustomizations(String packagePath)
3/2/2017 9:05:19 AM Error CreateProvisioningPackage: Failed to create Provisioning package 
 Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Common.Exceptions.ProvPackageException: PackageProvisioningSettings: Failed to package provisioning settings ---> System.Xml.XmlException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowInvalidChar(Char[] data, Int32 length, Int32 invCharPos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.Datastore.AssetApplySettingProvInfo.GetAssetApplySettingInfoValue()
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.Datastore.AssetApplySettingProvInfo.get_ProvValue()
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.Datastore.ProvXmlWriter.Write(String filePath)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.Datastore.PackageDatastore.WriteProvXmls(SettingEventType eventType, IEnumerable`1 settingProvInfo, IVariant variant)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.Datastore.PackageDatastore.Create(IImageCustomizations imageCustomizations, String directoryPath)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.ProvisioningPackage.PackageProvisioningSettings(IImageCustomizations imageCustomizations)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.ProvisioningPackage.PackageProvisioningSettings(IImageCustomizations imageCustomizations)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.ProvisioningPackage.PackageCustomizations(String packagePath)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.ProvisioningPackage.Export(String outputPath, Boolean includeICB, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Core.Wizards.Contexts.ProvisioningPackageCreationContext.CreateProvisioningPackage(IProvisioningPackageCreationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Xml.XmlException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowInvalidChar(Char[] data, Int32 length, Int32 invCharPos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.Datastore.AssetApplySettingProvInfo.GetAssetApplySettingInfoValue()
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.Datastore.AssetApplySettingProvInfo.get_ProvValue()
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.Datastore.ProvXmlWriter.Write(String filePath)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.Datastore.PackageDatastore.WriteProvXmls(SettingEventType eventType, IEnumerable`1 settingProvInfo, IVariant variant)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.Datastore.PackageDatastore.Create(IImageCustomizations imageCustomizations, String directoryPath)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ICD.Provisioning.ProvPackage.ProvisioningPackage.PackageProvisioningSettings(IImageCustomizations imageCustomizations)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the iotuapcommerical.xml file?

You can find the iotuapcommerical.xml in path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft IoT" after you download the [ISO file](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53899) and install it.

Then you will build the package successfully.